# What is the run time complexity of this for loop?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I am trying to find out the run-time complexity of this algorithm.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

  for (int N=100; N<=1000000; N=N*5) {  
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {     
      for (int j = 1; j <= Math.pow(N,1.5); j++) {
      i = i*2;
      j = j*2;
      Thread.sleep(10); 
     } 
    }
   long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long elapsed = (long)(stop - start);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("For N=" + N + " RT in msec: "+elapsed); 
 }
}
```

The first for loop:

```
for (int N=100; N<=1000000; N=N*5) // runs n/5 times, so O(n).
```

The first inner loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) // runs n times.
```

The second inner loop:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= Math.pow(N,1.5); j++) { // we can consider Math.pow O(1)
      i = i*2;
      j = j*2;
      Thread.sleep(10); 
     }
```

So by multiplying all O(n) * O(n) * O(1) = O(n^2) 
Is my answer correct? I am a little confused on this. 
Will appreciate any clarification on this. Thank You

Comment: Is that outer loop over `N` supposed to be included? That doesn't make a lot of sense (everything collapses to a constant) and does not look like it was intended, looks like more like that is a loop that tests the "inner parts" for various values of `N`

Comment: @harold yes, you are correct, the outer loop is not meant to be included. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @harold in that case, the final answer would be O(n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first loop is actually `O(k)` which `5^k = N`. Hence, `k = log_5(N)`.
The first inner loop is true (in `O(n)`). 
And the second inner loop `j` is each time is times to `2`. Hence, it is `O(h)` which `2^h = N^1.5`. Therefore, `h = 1.5 log(N)`.

In sum, the algorithm is in `O(log_5(N) * N * log(N))  = O(N log^2(N))`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If I am just calculating the inner loops, will that be then: n * log(n) = O(n log(n)) ?

Comment: @Prince my pleasure. Yes.